# Apache Zeppelin Pymongo Error

Tags: python, pymongo, apache-zeppelin

The following code on apache zeppelin (version 0.6.1)

```
%python
import pandas as pd
del(listResult)
listResult = list(collection.distinct("species",{"yr": yrs,"species":{"$ne":""}}))
df =  pd.DataFrame(listResult,columns=['Species sighted and/or captured this year'])
z.show(df)
```

only works at the first time i click "run all paragraphs". 
After that, if i run the paragraph, the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in show
  File "<stdin>", line 32, in show_dataframe
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

It only works againd when i restart python interpreter. Can you help me understand what's happening?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Could you share all paragraphs in the note?

Comment: Hi, in this link you can have the file : https://gitlab.com/cardosoj/speciesdata/blob/master/MARE-AnnualReport.json

Comment: I am getting 404. Maybe it's private repository in gitlab. You can use gist.github.com instead of

Comment: Can you try again please ?

Comment: I can see now your repository `speciesdata` but can't see any files in there. (I logged in also)

Comment: You can reproduce my issue by opening the chrome secret tab and access the page without login.

Comment: If it's not too long, you can post here or use gist instead of

Comment: Please try again with this link:https://gist.github.com/cardosojc/9b91af699e777eb16c532cfb376c6d2d

Comment: I am trying to reproduce but failing. Could you share your dataset? (db = client.mare, collection = db.fishdata)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cardosojc/ba70fb9d6ad4f5074c0b399e8a736de8 - you have a csv with some database records. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I've upgraded to zeppelin 6.2 and the error still occurs.